# Measuring for retrofit windows

Tags: windows, retrofit

We are looking to replace our old aluminum windows with retrofit vinyl. I've researched a bunch on how to measure it, and one thing that I have seen different opinions on is whether you need to remove some distance after you measure. Some sites say don't do that because the manufacturers already remove a half inch, but a bunch of places say to remove 1/4" to 3/8" off the width and height. Does anyone know which is right?

Comment: The 1/4 to 3/8 is for making the rough opening(in the wall) for a window.  Replacement window should be outsides of window frame(not trim) to fit.

Answer (score 1):

You **must** measure according to the instructions of the new window supplier.

You may get rough measurements for the purposes of cost estimates. However for the exact reason you posted, the final measurements have to be done by the manufacturers instructions.

Often the manufacturer will send a representative to your home to do the measurements. This is prefered. Then in the event of a window or windows not fitting it is on them and not your problem.